# Asking a Windows 10 related question. Is "superuser" appropiate for this?

Tags: discussion

Before I begin, I haven't been in here for a long time, and before I ask a question, I want to make sure it's thee right place to do it.

I have a kind of "problem" related with Windows 10, which is related to the windows.

I have seen people asking for help about Windows 10 in Super User as well in Stack Overflow.

My doubt is *which* is the best place to ask OS-related questions/issues, regardless of the issue.

(I'm not explaining the specific issue here as I don't see it strictly relevant. But if it is needed, I can explain the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Which is the best place to ask OS-related questions/issues

That depends on your question, but Windows 10 is generally on-topic for SuperUser.

For SuperUser the first thing to do is read our help pages:

- [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Please note that mobiles phones are explicitly off-topic on SuperUser.

There are alternative sites you might want to consider as well:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com for Apple questions
- https://askubuntu.com for Ubuntu questions
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for Linux questions, Unix and Unix-like such as OpenBSD and MacOS.
- https://serverfault.com/ for Server questions

Please read the help for those sites before asking there.

Comment: Okay, after reading the links you posted, I think "superuser" is the best place for my question

Comment: Just to note further: Each StackExchange site lists the topics that are on-topic on it in their Help section. There are often also examples of what isn't on-topic that might appear to be on-topic.